# building an image uploading / resizing script

Tags: php, ajax

I'd like to learn how to build my own basic script to upload/resize and rename an image.

Right now I'm using dropzone.js for the client-side code, but I'm struggling for the server-side.

Here is what my upload.php script looks like right now (from a dropzone tutorial):

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'user/avatar';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
?>
```

It's working fine, the image gets uploaded where I want, exept I don't understand how it works, and that may be problem for the next steps of my script.

- What is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` exactly ? Why is it not directly `$_FILES['file']['name']` ?
- How does `move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);` ? Why does it need $tempFile ?
- What's the difference between `$_FILES['file']` and `$_FILES['image']` ?
- Last question, what is the best approach now to set-up a basic resizing function ? My goal is to resize the image to 150*150px no matter its original size.

Hopefully I can get some help to figure out all this,

Thanks !

Comment: `$_FILES['file']` is `<input type="file" name ="file">`.  `$_FILES['image']` is the same but with the name attribute being `image`. `'tmp_name'` is the name of the file when stored on the server.

Comment: Hey chris85, thanks for your answer, indeed that makes sense (it wasn't that obvious because I'm using the jquery integration of dropzone, to use it in a div instead of a form, so I didn't have the `<input type="file" name ="file">`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, this is a Linux security thing. Linux uploads the file to a temporary folder, and only after it's done can it move the file from where it's uploaded to where you're wanting it to go. That's why you have to do the multiple steps.

As for resizing an image, I don't think you can do this directly. I think you have to use imagecopyresized().
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm going to check out your link and try out some things, however do you know "when" I should resize the image ? Before it is moved to its destination folder, or while it is in its "temporary form" ?

Comment: When theoretically should be irrelevant, but I would suggest doing it after it's moved to it's destination folder.